# Statement to predicate formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let B(x) mean “x is a bird”,

let W(x) mean “x is a worm”,

let E(x, y) mean “x eats y”.

There is a statement "Only birds eat worms".

If we translate this statement to predicate formula it will become: 
$∀x∀y(W(x) ∧ E(y, x) → B(y))$

I was wondering will it be the same as $∀x∀y(B(x) ∧ E(x, y) → W(y))$ ?

Comment: No; the second one means "Only worms are eaten by birds".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we translate this statement to predicate formula it will become: 
>   $∀x∀y(W(x) ∧ E(y, x) → B(y))$

Anything will be a bird *if* it eats anything which is a worm.

Any eater of worms is a bird.

Only birds eat worms.

> I was wondering will it be the same as $∀x∀y(B(x) ∧ E(x, y) → W(y))$ ?

Anything will be a worm *if* it is *eaten by* anything which is a bird.

Only worms are eaten by birds.

Comment: Yeah, this does make sense. I thought that if only birds eat worms then it is the same as only worms are eaten by birds. Thanks for clarifying, your answer helped a lot!